# data.table & devtools: install_github error - function works locally but not after installing package from github

Tags: r, data.table, devtools

I'm having trouble with the `data.table` package after installing a package from github using `devtools`. My custom function (which uses data.table functionality) works when I load the function locally, however when I create a custom package on github and install the package from github, the function no longer works.

Load the required packages:

```
require(PerformanceAnalytics)
if(!require(PerformanceAnalytics)) install.packages("PerformanceAnalytics");
require(PerformanceAnalytics)
require(data.table)
if(!require(data.table)) install.packages("data.table"); require(data.table)
require(devtools)
if(!require(devtools)) install.packages("devtools"); require(devtools)
```

Create a dummy dataset:

```
data(edhec)
EDHEC<-data.frame(date=index(edhec),coredata(edhec))
EDHEC<-melt(EDHEC,id.vars="date")
EDHEC<-data.table(EDHEC,key=c("variable","date"))
```

Install my package from github using devtools:

```
install_github("r_jfreels","jfreels"); require(jfreels)
```

Run my function:

```
test_date(EDHEC)
```

This gives an error: "Error in min(date) : invalid 'type' (closure) of argument"

Now create the function locally:

```
test_date<-function(DF) {
  DT<-data.table(date=DF$date,variable=DF$variable,value=DF$value,key=c('variable','value'))
  DT[,list(start_date=min(date),end_date=max(date)),by=variable]
}
```

Test the function again:

```
test_date(EDHEC)
```

This works.

This is driving me nuts and I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: whoa! Have you tried running R CMD check on a build of your package?

Answer (score 5):

If you add `Depends: data.table` to your DESCRIPTION file, it will "work".  However, you should really put in the effort to pass R CMD check -- right now, it's nowhere close to passing.

Comment: You're probably going to need to add dependencies for ggplot2, plyr, RColorBrewer, reshape2, xts, and whatever else you're using.  Instead of adding all those packages to Depends, you may want to add them to Imports and use `importFrom` in your NAMESPACE to import only the symbols you need.

Comment: @jfreels For future reference there was already a FAQ covering that Depends:data.table is needed. But admittedly data.table can be a bit tricky to depend or import from, due to inheritance from data.frame and the way that switch works. Search for "[data.table] cedta" for more info if needed.